# Multiplicar elemento dentro una clase

Tags: javascript

tengo que hacer un ejercicio que no logro resolver aún creyendo haberlo solucionado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ca">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Disc</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script>
 var x=new Producte("planxa",40);
function Producte(n,p){
this.nom=n;
this.preu=p;
iva = function(){
this.preu=this.preu*1.21;}
}
alert(x.nom);
alert(x.preu);
iva()
alert(x.preu);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente he de hacer que PREU = 40 se multiplique por 1.21. Pero no hay manera y me está sacando un poco de los nervios.

Decir que el código es dado de esta forma y NO puedo modificarlo (si lo hiciese a limpio con código propio, sería totalmente diferente).

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con esto exactamente: *«Decir que el código es dado de esta forma y NO puedo modificarlo (si lo hiciese a limpio con código propio, sería totalmente diferente).»*? ¿A que no puedes tener un método `setIVA()` por ejemplo? Explica con claridad cuáles son las restricciones que te imponen.

Comment: @A.Cedano Solo puede moficiarse lo básico, pero no rehacerse entero.

Comment: Lo propio sería crear un método `getWithIVA()` donde apliques el IVA y devuelvas el valor. El precio base nunca debería modificarse como intentas hacer en tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano solucionado, al final a iva le pasé una variable e hice un return de p * iva, y para acabar hice un alert(iva(1.21)); Y todo hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
iva=function(iva){
  return p * iva
    }
}
alert(x.nom);
alert(x.preu);
alert(iva(1.21));
```